# Is it possible to create dots using css and html?

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a mobile designing I need to be to represent  speaker portion using two rows of dots.Is it possible to design some dot's using html and css ?.I searched for a long time ,but I didn't get a relevant answer.Can any one help me?

I added a picture for better understanding .
[image]

Comment: What kind of dots do you need? Do you have an example?

Comment: @roy ,i added an image

Answer (score -1, accepted):

One way is to use radial gradient, less good browser support though

```css
.dots {
  height: 36px;
  background-image: -webkit-repeating-radial-gradient(center center, rgba(255,255,255,.4), rgba(255,255,255,.4) 4px, transparent 4px, transparent 100%);
  background-image: repeating-radial-gradient(center center, rgba(255,255,255,.4), rgba(255,255,255,.4) 4px, transparent 4px, transparent 100%);
  background-size: 12px 12px;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="dots"></div>
```

Comment: tnx ,perfect answer

Answer (score 4):

I'm inserting Unicode `&bull;` which looks like a • into a text portion of my HTML document.

It works with any browser, even if the visitor uses a custom CSS, disables JS, or anything else.

More @ http://character-code.com/arrows-html-codes.php

Comment: but how can i adjust the **margin** between them?

Comment: Use `letter-spacing` in CSS. It accepts any type of size-measurement.